# Should a non-annotated note after a flat note be flat?

Tags: notation

I am reading a measure of music (in bass clef) in which a flat E is followed by a non-annotated E.

[image]

Should that subsequent (4th) E note be played flat or natural? I feel like there should a natural symbol (♮) if the composer intended it to be played natural, right?

My musical software is playing that note flat. I just want to make sure that is not a bug. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called an accidental - even though it's there on purpose! An accidental in a bar will affect the note it's just before, and any other same place notes following *in the same bar*. Once the bar line is reached, that accidental ceases to have impact. If it's needed later, it needs re-instating, only to be cancelled by the following bar line. Uncannily, it *won't* affect any notes of the same name which are an octave or two away, only the note/s it precedes.

If it needs cancelling (e.g. Eb with accidental followed by Enat.) then the second E will have a natural sign before it.

All this is regardless of the key sig., and usually the result of a particular note not being included diatonically (in the key), in the manner that a 'changed' note, like an Enat in key Bb will need to be shown with an accidental.

Comment: Nice thorough answer, and upvoted particularly for including the subtle gotcha that the same note in a different octave *isn't* affected by the accidental ...